# My space between div doesn't work with float and margin

Tags: html, css

I have two divs like this:

**First div :**

```html
<div class="col-md-6" id="owner_name_76a62a154a220a104a16a203a196a25a92a71a58a216a222a172a64a" style="visibility: visible;float:left;margin-left:2px">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="user" style="color:#000a75;font-weight:bold">Général</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Second div :**

```html
<div class="col-md-2 px-4 chevron-down collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#76a62a154a220a104a16a203a196a25a92a71a58a216a222a172a64a" aria-expanded="false" style="float:right;margin-right:2px">
  <i class="material-icons float-right material-expand ripple" style="color: #0047FD !important;margin-right:2px">expand_more</i>
</div>
```

**This two div are in  :**

```html
<a class="mdc-list-item" data-placement="top" title="Acceuil" style="cursor:pointer;width:400px;margin-left:4px;margin-right:0em" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#76a62a154a220a104a16a203a196a25a92a71a58a216a222a172a64a">
  <div class="col-md-6" id="owner_name_76a62a154a220a104a16a203a196a25a92a71a58a216a222a172a64a" style="visibility: visible;float:left;margin-left:2px">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="user" style="color:#000a75;font-weight:bold">Général</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Collaspe zone-->
  <div class="col-md-2 px-4 chevron-down collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#76a62a154a220a104a16a203a196a25a92a71a58a216a222a172a64a" aria-expanded="false" style="float:right;margin-right:2px">
    <i class="material-icons float-right material-expand ripple" style="color: #0047FD !important;margin-right:2px">expand_more</i>
  </div>

</a>
```

**Here what it looks like :**

[image]

I want the space between the div to be greater than this , so i have tried with float and with margin but i have the same problem.

So i want the icon of expand more to be in the right margin 0 now it is in the center.

Comment: And what do you want to do?

Comment: I want the space between the div to be greater than this so i want the icon of expand more to be in the right margin 0 click to the image and you will understand the icone is in center

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? (col-md-6) , Where is the Javascript that trigger the collapse? beacuse we can't see the final result without it

Comment: @FrancescoFortin yes i'am using bootstrap and it works the collapse my problem is not the collapse

Comment: Columns in the Bootstrap grid need to be children of a `.row` element to function properly, yours aren’t. And if you want the second column to move over more to the right, you can achieve that for example by the column offset classes the framework provides. (Whether it makes sense to divide those two parts that rather belong together into different columns to begin with, would be a different question. I would probably rather put both into one column, and align only the chevron to the right inside of that.)

Comment: @misorude i have this in the top of <a>  (    <div  id="row_0" style="border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;">  )

Comment: An ID is not the same thing as a class, and the immediate _parent_ element of columns needs to have that class.

Comment: @misorude okey i have added class=row than what i do ?

Comment: What I already said …? If you don’t know how the offset classes provided by Bootstrap work, go read up on it in the documentation please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved ! i followed this [exemple](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

```js
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
         <div class="row">
            <span class="user" style="color:#000a75;font-weight:bold">Général</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
         <div class="col-md-2 px-4 chevron-down collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#76a62a154a220a104a16a203a196a25a92a71a58a216a222a172a64a" aria-expanded="false" style="float:right;margin-right:2px">
            <i class="material-icons float-right material-expand ripple" style="color: #0047FD !important;margin-right:2px">expand_more</i>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a good practice, you need to learn how the bootstrap grid work or you wil do a mess in later stages. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1):

I think your codes is not completely posted here, so we have a difference in viewing. 
But I see in your codes, the width has been set as fixed value `400px`. That's why the icon could not move to right. Please remove the `width:400px;` in the `a` tag.

Maybe when you run code at your side, the `a` tag has been set `display: block/inline-block .etc..` So you can see it can not move to right. That why we can not understand what you want.

Comment: I did that but i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I need more details.
Just used d-flex from bootstrap.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- just to show it whit boostrap -->

<a class="mdc-list-item" data-placement="top" title="Acceuil" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#76a62a154a220a104a16a203a196a25a92a71a58a216a222a172a64a">
  <div class="d-flex" id="owner_name_76a62a154a220a104a16a203a196a25a92a71a58a216a222a172a64a" style="visibility: visible;">
    <div>
      <span class="user" style="color:#000a75;font-weight:bold">Général</span>
    </div>
        <!--Collaspe zone-->
    <div class="ml-auto px-4 chevron-down collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#76a62a154a220a104a16a203a196a25a92a71a58a216a222a172a64a" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="material-icons float-right material-expand ripple" style="color: #0047FD !important;margin-right:2px">expand_more</i>
    </div>
  </div>



</a>
```

Comment: I did that and i added float , margin but i have the same problem

Comment: I'm using the flexbox you don't need the float Post a bigger slice of you code pls

Comment: My problem was solved see my answer thank you for your help